# Percentage width for fixed elements?

Tags: html, css

I have html like this:

```
<div id='content'>
    <div id='first'>...</div>
    <div id='second'>...</div>
</div>

#content
{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px;
}

#first
{
    width:70%;
    position:relative;
}

#second
{
    width:70%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

this causes the second div to be a bit wider (40px to be exact) than the first div, because the first div's 70% is with respect to the content's width (which is 100% minus the padding of 20px on each side).

What does the second div's 70% refer to? How could I make it so that the two divs are the same width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set an absolute width using javascript to detect the computed width of #first.

Answer (score 7):

The first `div`'s 70% refers to 70% of the width of `#content`.

The second `div`'s 70% refers to 70% of the width of the viewport.

If you add this CSS, the two `div`'s are the same width:

```
html, body {
    margin:0; padding:0
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrhVn/embedded/result/)

Comment: This only fixes it if you don't have a `width` specified on the body and also if the content has `width:100%`.

Comment: @Drackir: You're right, but the question did seem a little contrived, so I answered it at face value. The real easiest way to make it "work": get rid of *all* the `position` rules (and the `width:100%`).

Comment: How does having no margins/paddings on the body change the second div's width?

Comment: @Razor Storm: because the % width of a fixed element is based on the viewport. If the viewport, in your case, do have a margin-padding, it will affect the rendered width of the fixed element

Comment: In addition: You can easily get the result you want to obtain because both content and body have the width set to 100%. If the content has a fixed width, the 'second' element won't take care about 'content' element. It just refers to the viewport! As @Drackir well explained!

Comment: OK so lets say my screen size is 1000px wide. That means #content will be 1000px wide and has a useable width of 960px (1000px width - 40px of paddings). So #first will have a width of 672px (960px * 70%). Now, body will be 1000px wide, and since you said to make it no margin-padding, then the useable width is also 1000px. Viewport is also 1000px width, and #second will be 700px (70% of 1000px), still not the same. =/ I see that in your demo it works, but I tried it on my site and I got the result that I just described.

Comment: "How does having no margins/paddings on the body change the second div's width" - it doesn't. It changes the width of the first `div`. For instance, if you set `body { padding:20px }`, the width of the first `div` will be `70% of 20*2` px smaller = 28px less width.

Comment: @thirtydot, the problem is the first div is smaller since it takes the padding of the content div, not that of body.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there is no general way to do what you're asking (if you aren't willing to `html, body {  margin:0; padding:0 }`), because you're mixing two different layout modes with `%` and `px`. I think you need to post a link to your site if possible, or at least a more complete HTML/CSS example.

Comment: Well I'm not saying I'm not willing to do `html, body { margin:0; padding:0 }`, I did do that just that it didn't have the expected effect. Though, I just set an absolute width in javascript.

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on. See my previous comment regarding you providing a more complete example.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [CSS 2.1 Positioning Scheme spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme):

> In the case of handheld, projection,
>   screen, tty, and tv media types, the
>   box is fixed with respect to the
>   viewport...

This leads me to believe that the 70% you're setting is actually 70% of the viewport.

As far as making it the same width as the other div, perhaps you could use JavaScript (or specify widths explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

This weird behavior (great question!!) can be referred about the fact that the relative div (first) take the width looking at his father. The second one just look at the viewport, no matter who is its father (and what width is set to its father)!

This can fix your problem:

```
body,html{
    padding:0;
}
```

Edit -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/ETCZS/)