# Why is my site so wide. (tens of thousands of pixels)

Tags: css, width, scrollbars

A site I'm working on: http://bayhouse.biklopsdesign.com , is somehow INSANELY wide. This causing a horizontal scrollbar as well making fixed positioning really annoying.

Can anyone tell what's going on? I've been Firebugging for days with no relief. :/

Comment: It's because something in the html, css, or perhaps images on the site are making it that wide.  Personally, I'd simply look through the code for the text "width" and see if there's something set incorrectly.  Perhaps a div is supposed to be 800px wide, but someone mistyped a zero.

Comment: The problem is partly caused by your slider script. When you disable JS, you can see that it's not THAT bad (site is still a couple of pixels to wide though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was **hard** to find!

Your link `<a id="OTPoweredBy">...</a>` has a `margin` of `-9999px;`. If I set the `margin` to something more sensible, all the right-scrolling disappears.

Comment: I'm assuming, by the way, that you understand what `margin` means and how to use it - it's probably worth a separate question if you don't.

Comment: Oh god! Yes! I meant text-indent (I was just attempting a text-replacement). Thank you sir! I'm new to stackoverflow but consider your self +1'ed or one-upped or whatever means YOU RULE.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you have declared width as a percentage on fixed positioned elements. This takes a percentage of the *viewport*, not of the parent container.

So, for example, my viewport is 1900px wide. That means that every element that's set for `position: fixed; width: 100%` will be 1900px wide. You do this in a number of places, for example on `aside#text-15.header_area`. See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674562/percentage-width-for-fixed-elements).

Comment: Disabling javascript gets rid of the issue, so, it can't be a CSS issue.

Comment: I think the Javascript is setting the CSS. Removing those properties also fixes the issue (though it ends up ugly.)