# How to make navbar fixed in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make this template have a fixed navbar: [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/marketing-narrow.html)

I'm a beginner at CSS, so sorry about the silly question. When I try to make .masthead have position:fixed, the "Home About Contact" part disappears.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clarification: I'm looking to learn why adding position:fixed to the one above doesn't work, not looking for a replacement navbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**: 
When you set position:fixed, the width of the `masthead` becomes the size of the elements inside by default. Usually you would be able to declare `width:100%` on the `masthead` so it stretches the entire width of the parent div, but in this case, setting percentage width on the fixed element makes it calculate based on the width of the *viewport*: see here for more details:
[Percentage width for fixed elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674562/percentage-width-for-fixed-elements)

Since the rest of the content has a `max-width` of 700px, we can set the width of the `masthead` to also be 700px but the issue is when you shrink the viewport, the rest of the page will shrink but the `masthead` won't. Setting `max-width` on the masthead doesn't work because its original width is less than 700px.

```
.masthead {
position: fixed;
width: 700px;
top: 0;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(220,220,220);
}
```

Note that we set the background to white otherwise the bar will by default have a transparent background and the elements underneath will just intersect -- very ugly. We set the `top` property to 0 so it is now attached to the top of the page and doesn't leave a gap when we scroll.

(The border I added was just for looks, you can remove that if you'd like.)

Since we set the `masthead` to `fixed` positioning, it is now removed from the page flow, so everything else in the page acts like the `masthead` wasn't there. That leads to an issue: everything in the page shifts up, and one of the `<hr />`s on the top becomes hidden. To solve this, we add a `margin-top: 50px;` to the top `<hr />`, and everything is shifted downwards.

Due to the default margin styling (`margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 0;)` on `.nav`s in bootstrap the "Home About Contact" section ends up looking a bit awkward. We fix this by setting the margins to something more appropriate: `margin: 14px 0;`

**Quick Note**: I applied all these styles as inline in the chrome web inspector, so that they would override any other properties

**Edit**: Actually, it works nicely too if you just delete the HR from the document with the web inspector

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked great and it was a perfect explanation. You are a God among men.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add some CSS to the header so it can be used as a fixed header. It needs a background color, and a given width:

```
.masthead {
    width: 700px;
    background: white;
}
```

Then, because the header is not aligned with the top of the page, you'll need some javascript to make it *stick* to the top:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var div = $('.masthead');
    var start = $(div).offset().top;
        
    $.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
         var p = $(window).scrollTop();
         $(div).css('position',((p)>start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
         $(div).css('top',((p)>start) ? '0px' : '');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works! Is there a way to not have to use Javascript though? Also, for some reason, if I move the <hr> inside the masthead, it doesn't extend all the way across. I'd like the HR to "stick" along with the rest of it. Could you help me with that regard?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [boostrap navbar docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs)

Here is an example of a fixed navbar using bootstrap:

```
       <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="position: absolute;">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container" style="width: auto; padding: 0 20px;">
              <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a navbar that works with `position: fixed`:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='navbar'>
        <div align='right'> <a class='menu1 menu-item'>Home</a>
 <a class='menu2 menu-item'>About</a>
 <a class='menu3 menu-item'>Contact</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H9mMk/3/